# When I load my php page then submit button automatically press and page again and again loading?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using wamp server php my admin sql,table created connection every thing is fine,I'm working on local host, but page again and gain loading, not move down cursor etc, submit button automatically click ?

Here is screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO3Ky.jpg

```
       <center><form method="post">
       <table border="0" cellspacing="8">
       <tr>
          <td><label><b>*Select Campus:</b></label></td>
             <td>
            <select name="city" id="city">
                <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
                <option value="Isb">Islamabad</option>
                <option value="Abt">Abbotabad</option>
                <option value="wah">Wah</option>
                <option value="Atk">Attock</option>
                <option value="shw">Sahiwal</option>
                <option value="veh">Vehari</option>
                <option value="vir">Virtual</option>
            </select>
            <font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['campus'];?></font>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label><b>*Name</b></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /> 
   <font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['newname'];?></font>
   <td></tr>
   <br/>
    <tr>
   <td><label><b>*Login</b></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="logid"/>
    <font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['logname'];?></font> 
    <td></tr>
    <br/>
    <tr>
   <td><label><b>*Email Address</b></label></td>
   <td><input type="text"type="require" name="email"/>
   <font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['emailname'];?></font>
   </td></tr>
   <br/>
   <tr>
   <td><label><b>*Password</b></label></td>
   <td><input type="password" type="require" name="pass"/>
  <font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['passname'];?></font>
  </td></tr>
 <br/>
 <tr>
<td><label><b>*Retype Password</b></label></td>
<td><input type="password" type="require" name="rpass"/>
<font color="red"><?php echo @$_GET['rpassname'];?></font>
</td></tr>

 </table>
 <table border="0">
 <tr id="bu">
 <td ><input type="submit" id="cl" value="sign up"name="submit"/></td>    </tr>

 </table>
 </form>
 </center>










 <?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root' , '','example');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))<?php
 { 
$campus=$_POST['city'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$u_id = $_POST['logid'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$rpass = $_POST['rpass'];
if($campus==''){
echo
"<script>window.open('Log.php?campus=Select campus is    Required','_self')    
</script>";
exit();
}
if($name==''){
echo
"<script>window.open('Log.php?newname=Name is Required','_self')   </script>";
 exit();
 if($u_id==''){
echo
"<script>window.open('Log.php?logname=User ID is Required','_self')</script>";
        exit();
   }
   if($email==''){
   echo
  "<script>window.open('Log.php?emailname=Email is Required','_self')      </script>";
   exit();
  }
  if($pass==''){
   echo
   "<script>window.open('Log.php?passname=Password is Required','_self')   </script>";
    exit();
   }
   if($rpass==''){
   echo
   "<script>window.open('Log.php?rpassname=Password is Required','_self')  </script>";
exit();


}


 $sql = "INSERT INTO      student(Campus,User_id,Login,Email,password,Retype_password)    values('$campus','$name','$u_id','$email','$pass','$rpass')";

 if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql) {
echo "New record created successfully";
 print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>'; // Prompts   the user
    print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; //   redirects to register.php
}     else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }$conn->close();
 }
?>
```

Comment: remove <?php after 'if(isset($_POST['submit']))' and also you have not complete the brace '{...}' in your if conditions properly.

Comment: tomorrow this code is working fine,,every thing is fine but now its loading again and again,,submit button automatically press and page not move down again load ,plx help me,,, {} braces will be fine,,one bracket { at starting and other is at end ..I try ,i modified but same problem here

Comment: can you please post the code of your log.php file????

Comment: How can i uplaod here?can u give me your yahoo/gmail id or other ,i send you through email... this is my 1st post in this site

Comment: well here is my screen shots ,u can see here http://i.imgur.com/QC6RtAg.jpg?1

Comment: You need to correct your code firstly: • remove the `<?php` at the end of line 69, • add a `)` before `{` in the line 110, • insert a `}` at the end of the line 86; after correcting your code it just worked fine without the weird problem of yours!